# Not cookies send with delete, put... but POST is okay

Tags: post, cookies, cross-domain

Hello guys i have a small project but i need help :)
i dont say why my cookies is not send when i use method delete, put...
But when i send request with post or get is okay...

Front end

```
export const deleteAccount = async (idAccount) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.delete(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_ENV}/subaccount/${idAccount}`,
      {
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    )
    return response.data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error deleting account:", error)
    throw error
  }
}
```

Back end

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
require('dotenv').config();

var authRouter = require('./routes/private/auth');
var publicOfferRouter = require('./routes/public/offer');
var privateOfferRouter = require('./routes/private/offer');
var privateSubAccountRouter = require('./routes/private/subAccount');
var privateUserRouter = require('./routes/private/user');
var privateCtaRouter = require('./routes/private/cta');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Add headers before the routes are defined
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', process.env.DOMAIN);

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});
```

and the message error:

dashboard:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/subaccount/56' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok